# some of his most characteristic work or some of his most characteristic works?

Tags: grammar, american-english

I am a Korean English teacher. I am teaching about Monet. 
But I have encountered a grammatically strange expression like the following first sentence.
https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1551703/Cataracts-the-key-to-Monets-blurry-style.html
Monet suffered from cataracts for much of his later life. 
During that time, he produced some of his most characteristic work.

During that time, he produced some of his most characteristic works.

I think that in the sentence, the word “work” must be changed into “works.”
Am I wrong or is the original incorrect?
Could you please explain which is correct or incorrect?

Comment: His most renowned work is.....  Some of his most characteristic works are...

Comment: So you mean the original on the website is incorrect, right?

Comment: My reading of this can go either way, in American usage; the Telegraph is a British paper, however, and will follow British usage. In American usage, _Monet's works_ would refer to his individual paintings as a collective, while _Monet's work_ would refer to his entire corpus (or a definable subset thereof) as a single entity. (_I have a feeling that I'm **not** explaining this adequately, but..._)

Comment: Both "work" and "works" are idiomatic in this context, however they carry slightly different senses. "Work" would refer to Monet's work in general. e.g. "The artist did some of his most important work in his early life, when he produced the following works:..."

Comment: @JeffZeitlin You have explained it perfectly, but the position is absolutely no different in Britain. What the Telegraph is saying is that Monet produced some of his most characteristic work. They could almost equally have said "works", but had they done so they would have been referring to individual paintings.

Comment: @WS2 - Thank you; I felt that I could not speak for British usage, simply because it is not directly part of my environment and experience.

Comment: So you mean both work and works are grammatically correct?

Comment: @SuwonKim Yes - but are used in slightly different senses.

Comment: Monet’s *works* are the things that he created. However, he also did a lot of things to promote his philosophy of art, which were important, but not so tangible, e.g. https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Société_anonyme_des_artistes_peintres,_sculpteurs_et_graveurs. When you refer to *Monet’s work*, you capture all of this.

Answer (score 1):

Partially, it's a difference in British vs. American English conventions; if you're used to American conventions that phrase sounds odd.  For example "news about sporting events" is referred to as "Sports" on American news, but only "Sport" on British ones.

Technically it is correct, just uncommon:
**[WORK](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/work)**

> noun: the total output of a writer or artist (or a substantial part of it)
> *“Picasso's **work** can be divided into periods”*
>
> Synonyms: body of work, oeuvre

Comment: If you were an English teacher, which would you choose to teach your students? I would respect your choice. because I like a general usage.

Comment: Why do you think it’s uncommon? I’m pretty sure it’s just correct, period (including in American English, and not even technically).

Comment: @Ry - Only because I had to go through about seven online dictionaries to find the definition of work (singular) that includes "the total output" even though I knew it was correct.  Most dictionaries I saw regarding this issue _only_ have the singular usage ("**a single** piece of art or a product") and then use the plural _"works"_ to refer to a body of work.  Bizarrely, they'll include "work" as a synonym for "body of work," but don't include "body of work" as a definition of work.

Comment: @SuwonKim - Well, the actual answer to your question (work or works) is that both are correct.  When it comes to teaching I'm not sure what to say.  I would go to the English Language Learners forum and ask a question like _"Please help me understand the differences between work (a single product) versus work (a total output) versus works (a collection of single products)"_ and see what they say.  Sorry I can't be of more help.